# Shape and Textboxes are not Printing properly within Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am printing textboxes and shapes in excel 2019. but on right hand side of cell shapes are going outside cell and not getting printed correctly. but on left hand side, top, bottom space and margin remain same. this happen only with print preview and print.

I have tried followings:
1) Move but don't size Shape with cell
2) Check and uncheck aspect ration
3) Tried monospace type font for columns width issue

Please have a look at screenshots
[image: Main]

[image: Page layout]

[image: Print Preview]

Comment: Do you try printing using VBA? Excel prints only what is inside the selection. Would you like that VBA to extend selection in order to include all shapes intersecting with initial selection?

Comment: I am not sure how it will work. but i found a solutions after lot of research. i am sharing workaround below. please let me know if its right way.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

After hours of googling. i found two workarounds.

1) go to "Find and Select" under the "Home Tab,"
click "Select Objects,"
press ctrl-A to select all objects on your spreadsheet
go to the drawing tools "Format" tab
open the "Group" drop-down
select "Group"
then print/save to pdf
Should keep everything good looking. :)

Tested by me as a working solution.

Workaround 2
2) Go to Page Layout
In the drop down box "Fonts", when you hover over the options, you should see your columns resizing.
Now select "Metro"

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2007/shapespictures-printing-distorted-eg-flattened/52681443-6b50-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?messageId=d25da00e-1654-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5&page=2

Regarding 2nd workaround. i am not finding metro theme in my excel 2019. but it seems to be working solution for may people with similar issue.